# Why is jQuery script working on jFiddle, but not working on my local machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jFiddle code below, pasted into a notepad document. When I launch the html file, the browser(Chrome, Firefox, nor i.e. 11) do not display anything other than the HTML code. This is what it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfs2M/2/  Any ideas on why the grid in jQuery does not display?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
(function (GRASP, $) {
  var GRID_ROWS,
  GRID_COLS,
  GRID_ELEMENT;

GRASP.config = {
    gridContainer: "grid",
    matrixContainer: "matrix",
    matrixHeader: "matrixHeader"
};

GRASP.start = function () {
    GRID_ROWS = $("#rows").val();
    GRID_COLS = $("#cols").val();
    createGrid();
};

function createGrid() {
    GRID_ELEMENT = $("#" + GRASP.config.gri5dContainer);
    var cell; // Contains the 1 or 0 based upon the cell selection
    var newGrid = $('<div id="grid" class="gridContainer" ></div>');


    for (var i = 1; i <= GRID_ROWS; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= GRID_COLS; j++) {
            $("<div class='cell' data-hover-text='"+i+","+j+"'>0</div>")
                .appendTo(newGrid)
                .on("click", cellClick);
        }
    }

    newGrid.height(38 * GRID_ROWS);
    newGrid.width(38 * GRID_COLS);

    GRID_ELEMENT.replaceWith(newGrid);
}

function cellClick() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "0" ? "1" : "0");
}


}(window.GRASP = window.GRASP || {}, jQuery)); $(document).ready(function () {
GRASP.start();
});
</script>
</head>
<body >
<a href = "Practice Website.html"> Back to Page 1 </a>
<div id="gridLayout" class="gridLayout">
<div id="gridHeader">
<h2>Grid Configuration:</h2>
Grid Size:
<input id="rows" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="10" width="40"    size="3" onChange="GRASP.start();"/>x
        <input id="cols" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="10" width="40" size="3" onChange="GRASP.start();"/>
     </div>
        <div id="grid" class="gridContainer"></div>
</div>
</body>

<style>
  .gridContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.cell {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-style: solid outset;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cell:hover {
  background: #00CCFF;
}
.cell:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-hover-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  font-size: x-small;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #444444;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Open your console (hit F12). What error do you see?

Comment: General pro-tip: `<style>` belongs in the `<head>` and it's generally best to put your `<script>`s at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: jsfiddle runs JS `onload` by default, and `<script>` tags run while the document is being parsed (and most DOM nodes don't exist yet).

Comment: you have typos in code shown vs what is in demo `GRASP.config.gri5dContainer` is undefined

Answer (score 3):

Put all of your `scripts` at the bottom of the page.

You want your `jQuery` to execute after the page is loaded not before. As is, your jQuery is executed before your page is even rendered so calls to `$("#rows")` should return null.

Comment: but `GRASP.start()` is called in `$(document).ready(function () ` so this answer is incorrect about OP's execution which will be after elements exist. Does not answer OP's question or problem

Comment: @charlietfl `GRASP.start()` may be called on document ready, however the rest of the functions are initialized and pointing to DOM elements as they are read. Meaning the helper functions are all pointing to `null` types instead of DOM elements

Comment: no they aren't...they aren't invoked until `GRASP.start()`. The whole problem in the code is a typo

Comment: My bad, I think you may be right. I was confusing functional programming declarations with jQuery function definitions, oops!

Comment: see demo in my answer...code works fine when typo is fixed

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript, you have a reference error:

`GRID_ELEMENT = $("#" + GRASP.config.gri5dContainer);`

I believe you meant for that to be `GRASP.config.gridContainer`. My guess is that it's a typo. I corrected this and it worked locally.

Also:
Everyone else has made some good suggestions about improving your quality:

1. Style block in the head
2. Load the scripts at the end

Comment: nothing wrong with #3 ... jQuery is loading before OP code. That is not a valid issue

Comment: @charlietfl I missed that he's executing it after a `$(document).ready()` Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Fix the typo for `GRASP.config.gri5dContainer` and the code works fine as seen in [**this demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KotGsotoMity6jUgX3M?p=preview)

Should be `GRASP.config.gridContainer`